# How to reset System Variable PATH after tesseract installation

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables, tesseract

I downloaded and installed **tesseract-ocr-setup-3.05.00dev.exe** from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki and ticked the ***Add to Path*** and ***Set TESSDATA_PREFIX variable*** upon installation.

It used to be that my System Path consisted of many things including Python, Node, Npm, etc. Now, it is just a single item of Tesseract (see image)

[image: Path Variable Overwritten]

How can I get back my System Path Variables?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Tesseract 3.05.00 the Add to Path checkbox was removed, as it caused problems. [UB-Mannhaim documentation](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki):

> Old versions of the installer had an option to add Tesseract to the
>   PATH environment variable. That option was disabled by default. If it
>   was enabled and PATH was very long, it could happen that the new PATH
>   was empty. We suggest not to use that option and disabled it in our
>   latest version.

Following the UB-Mannhaim recommendation, instead of adding PATH to system variables you can always consider setting a local variable in your code.

Example from [pytesseract documentation](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract):

```
# If you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH, include the following:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
# Example tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
```

Another example for [pyocr](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/pyocr/blob/master/src/pyocr/tesseract.py):

```
pyocr.tesseract.TESSERACT_CMD = r'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
```

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/a/265575

Restoring System PATH:
Open Regedit

1. List item
   2.Select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
2. File->Load Hive
3. Navigate to your C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack, click the little button to the right of "Open" for "Show Previous Versions": enter image description here**
4. Select appropriate revision
5. Select SYSTEM.OLD***
6. Give it a name (e.g. "Old")
7. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\"Old"\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment
8. Open the PATH value and copy it to clipboard, then paste into system environment variables screen.

** I had to use [shadowexplorer](http://www.shadowexplorer.com/) to export my RegBack first, because it was "currently in use"

*** I just selected SYSTEM