# python import : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesser'

Tags: python, anaconda, ocr, pytesser

Hi I am new to python and OCR. I am trying to implement OCR. I have installed all the dependencies which are required for OCR. Also important thing is I am using Python provided by Anaconda custom. So when I tried to import pytesser it shows me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesser'`. I am trying to execute one simple following program :

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
from PIL import Image
from pytesser import *

image_file = 'imageSample1.jpg'
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = image_to_string(im)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file, graceful_errors=True)
print ("=====output=======\n")
print (text)
```

And got the following output :

```
nilkash@nilkash:~/ubuntuBackup/My_Folder/Its_my_work/DS/ML&AI/ImageRecognition$ python SampleImageContentRecognition.py 
['/home/nilkash/ubuntuBackup/My_Folder/Its_my_work/DS/ML&AI/ImageRecognition', '/home/nilkash/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip', '/home/nilkash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6', '/home/nilkash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/nilkash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/nilkash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg', '/home/nilkash/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SampleImageContentRecognition.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pytesser import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesser'
```

I believe because conda distribution of python it is not able to use it. Is there any way to link it. Or I am doing any thing wrong. Need some help. Thank you.

I drill down to the problem a bit. I have two python version installed one is python2.7 and another one is python3.6. So my all pytesseract configuration are with python2.7. but I am using version 3.6. So I think what I need to do is remove all pytesseract and install against python3.6. Or else move all config to point python3.6. I tried to conda version of pytesseract via `conda install -c auto pytesseract` but got the following error :

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pytesseract -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Is there any way to resolve this. Need some help.

Comment: Did you verify that you install all dependencies with the Anaconda Python instance? Or do you have multiple Python instances installed and maybe installed your dependencies into a different one?

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to use PIP in your anaconda prompt
[Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)

Open the anaconda comand line prompt and install your packages with pip

ie

```
pip install pytesseract
```

Comment: Thomas Thank you for quick replay. I tried to install pytesseract in specific env of conda. I tried it with following way : `conda install -n root pytesseract` but it says `PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels: - pytesseract` .  Is there any other way to install in conda env?

Comment: Yeah i tried with pip and it says `Requirement already satisfied: pytesseract in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Comment: but in the same terminal if i try to import it it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesser'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks they are not under the same path and python can not find it.

Please refer to this link:

[How to reset System Variable PATH after tesseract installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014724/how-to-reset-system-variable-path-after-tesseract-installation)